# preg_match error for a String

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match-all, substr

I have a String

```
$dim = "64×191×75"
```

This String is basically Width x Height x Depth. And I want to Separate the values.
The Code I have written is :

```
<?php 
$dim = "64×191×75"
preg_match_all("'x(.*?)x'si",$dim,$dim_h);

$dimension['height'] = $dim_h[1][0];
$dimension['width'] = strstr($dim,'x',true);
$dimension['depth'] = substr(strrchr($dim,"x"),1);

var_dump($dimension);
exit();

This is Dump. I get along with a Notice. That Offset for $dim_h doesn't exist.
array (size=3)
'height' => null
'width' => boolean false
'depth' => boolean false
```

I am unable to find any reason for the string function to not work. But not sure of the pregmatch. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: **1.** you have there syntax errors (semicolon at the end of 2nd line). **2.** in string you have `×` (times), in regex `x` (letter X).

Comment: Some basic debugging is in order.  Do `var_dump($dim_h)` to see what was returned by `preg_match()` first.  The whole thing is much more easily done with `preg_split()` though:  `$dimension = preg_split('/\s*×\s*/', $dim);` to split on the `x` with whitespace optionally surrounding it.

Comment: @Maharshi cant u use explode with a delimiter `x` instead?

Comment: thanks for the input guys. Working fine now with the use of Explod. Saved a few lines of code as well. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way:

```
    $dim = "64×191×75";

    $tmp = explode('x', $dim, 3);
    $dimension['height'] = $tmp[0];
    $dimension['width'] = $tmp[1];
    $dimension['depth'] = $tmp[2];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help man.. works absolutely fine with explode. This is the easier way. Appreciate it.